# Set value from textbox to another textbox

Tags: jquery, multiplication

I have a markup like this:

```
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtketdetail[]" id="txtketdetail" placeholder="Nama detail akun" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txtvolume[]" id="txtvolume" placeholder="Volume/Jumlah" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txthrgsatuan[]" id="txthrgsatuan" placeholder="Harga satuan" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txtjmlbiaya[]" id="txtjmlbiaya" placeholder="Jumlah biaya" required />
</div>
```

```js
$('input[id^="txthrgsatuan"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[id^="txthrgsatuan"]').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().next().children().val($(this).val()*$(this).parent().prev().children().val());
    });
});
```

I want to multiply `txthrgsatuan` with `txtvolume` and have the end result appear in `txtjmlbiaya` event trigger change `txthrgsatuan`. However there are troubles when I add another input with the same `name` an `id`. For more details see the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Please add your current code to the question

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with the same id on the page, you just cannot.

Comment: @Imaginaroom: i have generate id for new inputs. another input have id txthrgsatuan2, txthrgsatuan3, txthrgsatuan..N

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: this is current code i used
    $('input[id^="txthrgsatuan"]').on('change', function() {
        $('input[id^="txthrgsatuan"]').each(function() {
            $(this).parent().next().children().val($(this).val()*$(this).parent().prev().children().val());
        });
    });

Comment: use classes and indexes instead of ids when addding a new line, to know the line of the input being changed and then change the result in the same line

Comment: @Ryad.iv: can you tell me how the script should I write?

Comment: @gierg share your code for adding a new line

Comment: this full of my code sir...

[Full Code](https://jsfiddle.net/2bkj134x/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change duplicate id's to classes. Then set an `input` event on the desired input fields, fetch values and set them accordingly.

Here is a working demo.

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on("input", ".txthrgsatuan", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var otherVal = $(this).parent().prev().children().val();
    $(this).parent().next().children().val(val * otherVal);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control txtketdetail" name="txtketdetail[]" placeholder="Nama detail akun" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-number txtvolume" name="txtvolume[]" placeholder="Volume/Jumlah" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-number txthrgsatuan" name="txthrgsatuan[]" placeholder="Harga satuan" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-number txtjmlbiaya" name="txtjmlbiaya[]" placeholder="Jumlah biaya" required />
</div>
```

Comment: code only working to input the first line only, but in another line, the code not working.

Comment: I hope you have changed the ids to classes there?

Comment: ya, i have add class to every inputs.

Comment: @gierg check the updated answer. Have changed the handler a bit. `$(document).on("input"...`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("input", 'input[id^="txthrgsatuan"]', function () {
    $('[name="txthrgsatuan[]"]').each(function () {
        var intMultiplication = parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($(this).parent().prev().children().val());
        if (!isNaN(intMultiplication))
        {
            $(this).parent().next().children().val(intMultiplication);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtketdetail[]" id="txtketdetail" placeholder="Nama detail akun" required />
        </div>
        <div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-number" name="txtvolume[]" id="txtvolume" placeholder="Volume/Jumlah" required />
        </div>
        <div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-number" name="txthrgsatuan[]" id="txthrgsatuan" placeholder="Harga satuan" required />
        </div>
        <div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control input-number" name="txtjmlbiaya[]" id="txtjmlbiaya" placeholder="Jumlah biaya" required />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code will work on dynamic inputs as well. If you will use this code then you won't need to create dynamic `id` attribute of element.

Answer (score 0):

You can first start by adding classes to your inputs instead of ids. Then you get the parent element and then search using 'find()' and then multiply the two values:

```
$('.txtvolume, .txthrgsatuan').keyup( function(){
  var value_1 = $(this).val();
  var value_2 = $(this).parent().parent().find($(this).hasClass('txthrgsatuan') ?  '.txtvolume': '.txthrgsatuan').val();

  $(this).parent().parent().find('.txtjmlbiaya').val(value_1 * value_2);

});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtketdetail[]" id="txtketdetail" placeholder="Nama detail akun" required />
    </div>
    <div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-number txtvolume" name="txtvolume[]" placeholder="Volume/Jumlah" required />
    </div>
    <div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-number txthrgsatuan" name="txthrgsatuan[]" placeholder="Harga satuan" required />
    </div>
    <div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-number txtjmlbiaya" name="txtjmlbiaya[]" placeholder="Jumlah biaya" required />
    </div>

</div>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ejsk6jst/2/)

Comment: code only working to input the first line only, but in another line, the code not working.

Comment: sorry sir, this code not work for me. thanks a lot for your respons. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo, but change your ID's tho in this case the ids are assigned with number ie. `block 1` contains `idname2`, `block 2` contains `idname2`, and so on... this works for multiple blocks too.

```js
$('[id^="txtvolume"]').on('change keyup', function(){
 var thisVal = isNaN($(this).val())? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
    var $next = $(this).parent().next('div');
    var nextVal = isNaN($next.find('input').val())? 0 : parseInt($next.find('input').val());
    var $total = $next.next('div');
 var prod = isNaN(thisVal * nextVal)?0:thisVal * nextVal;
    $total.find('input').val(prod);
});


$('[id^="txthrgsatuan"]').on('change keyup', function(){
 var thisVal = isNaN($(this).val())? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
    var $prev = $(this).parent().prev('div');
    var prevVal = isNaN($prev.find('input').val())? 0 : parseInt($prev.find('input').val());
    var $total = $(this).parent().next('div');
 var prod = isNaN(thisVal * prevVal)?0:thisVal * prevVal;
    $total.find('input').val(prod);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtketdetail[]" id="txtketdetail1" placeholder="Nama detail akun" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txtvolume[]" id="txtvolume1" placeholder="Volume/Jumlah" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txthrgsatuan[]" id="txthrgsatuan1" placeholder="Harga satuan" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txtjmlbiaya[]" id="txtjmlbiaya1" placeholder="Jumlah biaya" required />
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtketdetail[]" id="txtketdetail2" placeholder="Nama detail akun" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txtvolume[]" id="txtvolume2" placeholder="Volume/Jumlah" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txthrgsatuan[]" id="txthrgsatuan2" placeholder="Harga satuan" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txtjmlbiaya[]" id="txtjmlbiaya2" placeholder="Jumlah biaya" required />
</div>
<br/><br/>

<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtketdetail[]" id="txtketdetail3" placeholder="Nama detail akun" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txtvolume[]" id="txtvolume3" placeholder="Volume/Jumlah" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txthrgsatuan[]" id="txthrgsatuan3" placeholder="Harga satuan" required />
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-sm col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-number" name="txtjmlbiaya[]" id="txtjmlbiaya3" placeholder="Jumlah biaya" required />
</div>
```